# Difference between vector <int> V[] and vector< vector<int> > V

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, vector

`vector <int> V[]` and `vector< vector<int> > V` both are **2D arrays**.

But what is the **difference between them** and where do we use each one? Please give a brief explanation.

Comment: Neither of these is a 2-D array.  Both are arrays of arrays.  The only syntax available in C++ for a 2-D array is the one inherited from C.  (Because `std::array` may have padding, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/19103244/103167)

Comment: @BenVoigt: How can a gold-badge C++ grok call any of those two an "array of arrays"?

Comment: @DevSolar: Because the English phrase "array of" is not especially precise.  If I say "I have an array of Widgets", I haven't told you whether I'm managing that array with a smart pointer / wrapper collection, or whether I'm holding the Widgets directly, via composition, by reference (using a pointer of course, since you can't have a collection whose element type is a C++ reference type).  So all of `Widget[N]`, `std::unique_ptr<Widget[]>`, `std::vector<Widget>`, `std::vector<WidgetBase*>`, `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Widget>>` are, in English, "array of Widget".  To be specific, say the type

Comment: In this case, there definitely are multiple arrays of `int`, (one held by each `std::vector<int>`), and these are themselves kept in another array.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I would *expect* any coworker to *not* call a `std::vector<>` an "array", ever. That's all I am saying.

Comment: @BenVoigt "2-D" C-style arrays are also actually arrays of arrays

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`vector<int> V[]` is an *array of vectors*.

`vector< vector<int> > V` is a *vector of vectors*.

### Using arrays are *C-style coding*, using vectors are *C++-style coding*.

Quoting [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) ,

> Vectors are sequence containers representing arrays that can **change in
>   size.**
>
> Just like arrays, vectors use *contiguous storage locations* for their
>   elements, which means that their elements can also be accessed using
>   offsets on regular pointers to its elements, and **just as efficiently
>   as in arrays**. But unlike arrays, their size can change dynamically,
>   with their storage being handled automatically by the container.

**TL;DR**:

When you want to work with a **fixed number** of `std::vector` elements, you can use `vector <int> V[]`.

When you want to work with a **dynamic array** of `std::vector`, you can use   `vector< vector<int> > V`.

Comment: I would prefer `std::array<vector<int>,n>` with `n` the length of the array over `std::array<vector>[]` The latter is a mismash of `C` style and `C++` style coding.

Comment: @tillaert: Who gave you the idea that the built-in types are "not C++"?

Comment: @BenVoigt I didn't say it's not C++, I was talking about coding styles.

Answer (score 16):

One difference would be that although both can be initialized in the same way, e.g.

```
vector<int> V1[]        {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
vector<vector<int>> V2  {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
```

and accessed

```
cout << V1[0].back() << endl;
cout << V2[0].back() << endl;
```

the V1 can't grow. You cannot make V1.push_back(...) as its not a vector object. Its just an array. Second one is dynamic. You can grow it as you please.

Comment: Also, you can't copy or assign the first one.

Answer (score 2):

`vector<vector<int>> v(26);` is a vector containing vectors. In this example, you have a vector with 26 vectors contained in it. The code `v[1].push_back(x)` means that `x` is pushed back to the first vector within the vectors.

`vector<int> a[26];` is an array of vectors. In other words, a one-dimensional array containing 26 vectors of integers. The code `a[1].push_back(x);` has `x` being pushed back to the first index of the array.

Answer (score 2):

`vector<int> v[]` is an array of vectors. That is, it is an array which contains vectors as its elements.
So, you cannot change the size of the array part, but we can add to its elements which is vector.

For example,

```
1.vector<int> v1[] = {{1},{2},{3}};   // array that contains 3 vector elements.
2.vector<vector<int>> v2 = {{1},{2},{3}};  // vector that contains 3 vector elements.
```

So for the first we cannot change the size of v but we can add or delete elements to its elements since it is a vector.

```
v1.push_back(4);   // this will give an error since we cannot the predefined size of array.
v1[1].push_back(4); // this is acceptable since we are changing the vector part.
```

This makes the v1 `{{1},{2,4},{3}}`

For the second one, we can change both the overall size and its elements.

```
 v2.push_back(4);  // this is acceptable since it is vector.
```

Answer (score 0):

vector V[] is just a fixed array; and so you can add/modify only till the upper limit. It is not a vector per se, and so has a fixed size limit.
However vector< vector > V is a dynamic vector and its size can be increased dynamically.