# 2D vector passing to a function in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

When I declare a vector like `vector<vector<int> >v` and try to pass it to a function like below it works:

```
int change(vector<vector<int> >&v)
{
    v[0][0]=-1;
}
int main()
{
    vector<vector<int> >v;
    int a[]={1,2,3};
    int b[]={4,5,6};
    v.push_back(vector<int>(a,a+3));
    v.push_back(vector<int>(b,b+3));
    change(v);
    cout<<v[0][0];
return 0;
}
```

But when I declare the vector like `vector<int>v[2]` and pass it to a function in the same way it's causing an error.

```
int change(vector<vector<int> >&v)
{
    v[0][0]=-1;
}
int main()
{
    vector<int>v[2];
    int a[]={1,2,3};
    int b[]={4,5,6};
    v[0]=vector<int>(a,a+3);
    v[1]=vector<int>(b,b+3);
    change(v);
    cout<<v[0][0];
return 0;
}
```

How can I do this and why is this causing an error?

Comment: The answers to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712364/difference-between-vector-int-v-and-vector-vectorint-v) tell you that `vector<int>v[2]` is an array of vectors, not a "2D vector".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example you declared an array of vector.

So you can use either :

```
int change(vector<int>(&v)[2])
```

or

```
int change(vector<int>v[]) // pointer
```

or

```
int change(vector<int>*v) // pointer
```

Comment: Those are passing a pointer to vector, not a vector by reference.

Comment: both works fine and i think it fullfils the expectation of OP...
what's wrong if i pass the vector this way?

Comment: What is wrong is you are saying it is passing by reference, but it really is passing a pointer to vector. Any pointer. It can be null, it can be a pointer to a single vector, it can be a pointer to an array of length 1 or 10000. You throw away the type information for no reason.

Comment: Your answer still has the same problems.

Answer (score -2):

how in hell could this work, you want implicit conversion from `vector<int>[]` to `vector<vector<int>>` ?
a vector is a object containing things, an array isn't that

note that an array dont need to be passed by reference, so

```
int change(vector<int> v[])
```

do the trick