# How to align std::array contained data?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, std, memory-alignment

Since `std::array` does not allow changing its allocator, is there a way to ensure that the pointer to the data address is aligned?

For instance, in GNU g++ 4.8.4 and 6.1.0, the code below

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  std::array<bool, 10> a;
  std::array<char, 10> b;
  std::array<int,10> c;
  std::array<long long, 10> d;
  std::array<float, 10> e;
  std::array<double, 10> f;

  std::cout << "array<bool,10>.data()       = " << a.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "array<char,10>.data()       = " << (void*) b.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "array<int,10>.data()        = " << c.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "array<long long, 10>.data() = " << d.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "array<float, 10>.data()     = " << e.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "array<double, 10>.data()    = " << f.data() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

provides the following output that shows that the container data is aligned to 16-byte addresses no matter the data-type contained when compiling for an x86-64 bit architecture.

```
array<bool,10>.data()       = 0x7ffe660a2e40
array<char,10>.data()       = 0x7ffe660a2e30
array<int,10>.data()        = 0x7ffe660a2e00
array<long long, 10>.data() = 0x7ffe660a2db0
array<float, 10>.data()     = 0x7ffe660a2d80
array<double, 10>.data()    = 0x7ffe660a2d30
```

However, for Intel's icpc v16.0.3 the result is shown below even using `-align`. While most of containers are aligned to 16-byte addresses, some (`char` and `float` arrays) are aligned to smaller byte addresses (2-byte and 8-byte, respectively).

```
array<bool,10>.data()       = 0x7ffdedcb6bf0
array<char,10>.data()       = 0x7ffdedcb6bfa
array<int,10>.data()        = 0x7ffdedcb6ba0
array<long long, 10>.data() = 0x7ffdedcb6b00
array<float, 10>.data()     = 0x7ffdedcb6bc8
array<double, 10>.data()    = 0x7ffdedcb6b50
```

**EDIT**

Just to exemplify the proposal from RustyX, this is the changed code

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  alignas(16) std::array<bool, 10> a;
  alignas(16) std::array<char, 10> b;
  alignas(16) std::array<int,10> c;
  alignas(16) std::array<long long, 10> d;
  alignas(16) std::array<float, 10> e;
  alignas(16) std::array<double, 10> f;

  std::cout << "array<bool,10>.data()       = " << a.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "array<char,10>.data()       = " << (void*) b.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "array<int,10>.data()        = " << c.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "array<long long, 10>.data() = " << d.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "array<float, 10>.data()     = " << e.data() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "array<double, 10>.data()    = " << f.data() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

and this is the result when compiling it with Intel's icpc v16.0.3.

```
array<bool,10>.data()       = 0x7ffe42433500
array<char,10>.data()       = 0x7ffe42433510
array<int,10>.data()        = 0x7ffe424334a0
array<long long, 10>.data() = 0x7ffe42433400
array<float, 10>.data()     = 0x7ffe424334d0
array<double, 10>.data()    = 0x7ffe42433450
```

Comment: std::array doesn't work with *any* allocator. It just contains a member `T data[N];`.

Comment: Yes, I know @Nawaz. That's why I'm asking :)

Comment: @RustyX thank you! I didn't know `alignas`. If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default the compiler will do the right thing when it comes to alignment.

But you can override it with `alignas`:

```
alignas(16) std::array<char, 10> b;
```

---

#### Postscriptum

It is interesting that the Intel compiler thinks it is sufficient to align a `char[]` on 8 bytes. It is as if it *knows* that on an x86 platform you gain little by aligning it any wider.

Keep in mind that too much alignment can *reduce performance* due to increased memory use and reduced cache efficiency. Modern x86 architectures (Sandy Bridge and newer) work very efficiently with unaligned data, but cannot compensate for partially used cache lines ([more info](http://lemire.me/blog/2012/05/31/data-alignment-for-speed-myth-or-reality/)).

Comment: `std::array` contains just the array of the elements. If you align it, you align the underlying array as well.

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Interestingly, icpc didn't align `array<char>` and `array<float>`.

Comment: I often use the following construct: `template <typename T, size_t N> struct __attribute__((aligned(16))) aligned_array : public std::array<T,N> {};` In this way I don't need to write `alignas` everywhere.

Comment: @JensMunk You may also do: `template<class T> struct alignas( 16 ) aligned_array {};`

Comment: @user2296177 No, that makes no sense. The portable way is `template <typename T, size_t N> struct alignas(16) aligned_array : public std::array<T,N> {};`. MSVC 2013 does not support this, so I didn't bother making it portable. I have a version for GCC and another for MSVC

Comment: @JensMunk I omitted the inheritance to keep the comment short. Did you mean that something else made no sense? If so, please tell me. I'd like to know what you meant!

Comment: Thanks for the Postscript @RustyX, it is very interesting.

Comment: GCC 6 and 7 actually will not always do the right thing.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651923/gcc-fails-to-optimize-aligned-stdarray-like-c-array

Comment: @Harald Note that the first element of the array/aggregate type will be aligned to your chosen byte boundary (using `alignas` or a custom aligned allocator). The following elements might not be aligned to said boundary. Not that this would concern someone, as the first element is what is normally needed, just adding this comment for completeness and since I was a little confused about this matter myself.

Comment: "std::array contains just the array of the elements. If you align it, you align the underlying array as well": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103244/is-the-size-of-stdarray-defined-by-standard seems to suggest otherwise, you might want to comment there as well, I don't know which is correct.

Comment: @CiroSantilli冠状病毒审查六四事件法轮功 see [\[class.mem\]/20](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.mem#20): "*A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a reinterpret_cast, points to its initial member*". So they must have the same address, and hence, the same alignment.