# Static vector internal data layout - `union` vs `std::aligned_storage_t` - huge performance difference

Tags: c++, optimization, language-lawyer, unions, c++17

Assume that you have to implement a `static_vector<T, N>` class, which is a **fixed capacity** container that entirely lives on the stack and never allocates, and exposes an `std::vector`-like interface. *(Boost provides [`boost::static_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost/container/small_vector.html).)*

Considering that we must have *uninitialized* storage for maximum `N` instances of `T`, there are multiple choices that can be made when designing the internal data layout:

- Single-member `union`:

  ```
  union U { T _x; };
  std::array<U, N> _data;
  ```
- Single `std::aligned_storage_t`:

  ```
  std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T) * N, alignof(T)> _data;
  ```
- Array of `std::aligned_storage_t`:

  ```
  using storage = std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>;
  std::array<storage, N> _data;
  ```

Regardless of the choice, creating the members will require the use of [**"placement `new`"**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) and accessing them will require something along the lines of `reinterpret_cast`.

---

Now assume that we have two very minimal implementations of `static_vector<T, N>`:

- `with_union`: implemented using the "single-member `union`" approach;
- `with_storage`: implemented using the "single `std::aligned_storage_t`" approach.

Let's perform the following benchmark using both `g++` and `clang++` with `-O3`. I used [**quick-bench.com** for this task](http://quick-bench.com/gDyJXa4-DcrvD9TM9IVl_XPrdWk):

```
void escape(void* p) { asm volatile("" : : "g"(p) : "memory"); }
void clobber()       { asm volatile("" : :        : "memory"); }

template <typename Vector>
void test()
{
    for(std::size_t j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    {
        clobber();
        Vector v;
        for(int i = 0; i < 123456; ++i) v.emplace_back(i);
        escape(&v);
    }
}
```

*(`escape` and `clobber` are taken from Chandler Carruth's CppCon 2015 talk: ["Tuning C++: Benchmarks, and CPUs, and Compilers! Oh My!"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk))*

- Results for `g++ 7.2` *([live here](http://quick-bench.com/gDyJXa4-DcrvD9TM9IVl_XPrdWk))*:

[image: g++ results]

- Results for `clang++ 5.0` *([live here](http://quick-bench.com/A3eByf3jjCBBr0QFxMhpgAxUXEA))*:

[image: clang++ results]

---

As you can see from the results, `g++` seems to be able to aggressively optimize *(vectorization)* the implementation that uses the "single `std::aligned_storage_t`" approach, but not the implementation using the `union`.

My questions are:

- **Is there anything in the Standard that prevents the implementation using `union` from being aggressively optimized?** *(I.e. does the Standard grant more freedom to the compiler when using `std::aligned_storage_t` - if so, why?)*
- **Is this purely a "quality of implementation" issue?**

Comment: Even more interesting is that gcc's `aligned_storage` is itself a union, though it's to an `unsigned char` array + a struct with an `__attribute__((__align__((T))))`.

Comment: Changing your union to store an array of unsigned char instead gives it the same timing as the aligned_storage implementation.

Comment: GCC is more permissive than required by the standard when coming to type-punning through unions, even with `-fstrict-aliasing` enabled. This might be the reason here.

Comment: May caused by the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43651923/gcc-fails-to-optimize-aligned-stdarray-like-c-array/43667221

Comment: "clang++ fails to aggressively optimize either of them." You sure? It looks like both clang times are comparable with the [faster] gcc aligned storage time.

Comment: @Barry: nope, I just failed at reading graphs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[xskxzr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645210/static-vector-internal-data-layout-union-vs-stdaligned-storage-t-huge#comment84292784_48645210) is right, this is the same issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43651923/2069064). Fundamentally, gcc is missing an optimization opportunity in forgetting that `std::array`'s data is aligned. John Zwinck helpfully reported [bug 80561](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80561).

You can verify this in your benchmark by making one of two changes to `with_union`:

1. Change `_data` from a `std::array<U, N>` to simply a `U[N]`. Performance becomes identical
2. Remind gcc that `_data` is actually aligned by changing the implementation of `emplace_back()` to:

   ```
   template <typename... Ts> 
   T& emplace_back(Ts&&... xs)
   {
       U* data = static_cast<U*>(__builtin_assume_aligned(_data.data(), alignof(U)));
       T* ptr = &data[_size++]._x;
       return *(new (ptr) T{std::forward<Ts>(xs)...});
   }
   ```

Either of those changes with the rest of your benchmark gets me comparable results between `WithUnion` and `WithAlignedStorage`.